# BabelNet- Your key is not valid or the daily requests limit has been reached

Tags: java

I have just registered my account on BabelNet but the execution of the sample code below give this error:

> Your key is not valid or the daily requests limit has been reached.

BabelNet site show 1000 request per day.

I have downloaded the babelnet BabelNet 4.0.1 API
public class BabelTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BabelNet bn=BabelNet.getInstance();
    for(BabelSynset synset:bn.getSynsets("volume", Language.EN)){
        System.out.println("Synset ID" +synset.getID());

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We do not have access to BabelNet's key store, so we will not be able to answer this.  You should contact BabelNet for assistance.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Babel... but where do you specify your access credentials / API key? Seems to me like a rate limit due to being unauthenticated.

Comment: Once you have registered,they sent a key to your inbox.And the doc indicates to put the key in the babelnet.properties file.But I still receive the error in my java code but if I'am running the URI online.I have received the answer